# pointcloud access data

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi

I have a subscribed topic with the type sensor_msgs::PointCloud2.

I do not need the pcl library. I just want to iterate through each point and take the Z value. but i have no clue how to do this with sensor_msgs::PointCloud2 and i dont find an example.

Do I really need pcl for easy element access?
Ciao

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/46388/pointcloud-access-data/) by [Pitscho](https://answers.ros.org/users/2751/pitscho/) on ROS Answers with karma: 36 on 2012-10-21

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Please look into the documentation of sensor_msgs::PointCloud2 (http://ros.org/doc/api/sensor_msgs/html/msg/PointCloud2.html) and you can use the field "data" to access z values.

Possible duplicate of this question (http://answers.ros.org/question/11556/datatype-to-access-pointcloud2/)

---

Originally posted by [harsha](https://answers.ros.org/users/3217/harsha/) with karma: 91 on 2012-10-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [peci1](https://answers.ros.org/users/7736/peci1/) on 2015-08-13**:
Since Indigo, things have changed. See my answer to the possible duplicate question: http://answers.ros.org/question/11556/datatype-to-access-pointcloud2/?answer=215829#post-id-215829